# Helm external public chart

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Basic question which I don't seem to find a concrete answer to. How should I keep track of external public charts?

Let's say I want to make use of the :

Kubernetes SIGs AWS Load balancer controller:
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/deploy/installation/

I could "imperatively" do the following:

Add the Helm repo:

```
helm repo add eks https://aws.github.io/eks-charts
```

Get the image input values

```
helm show values eks/aws-load-balancer-controller > values.yml
```

Update the `clusterName` and install

Install the helm chart if not using IAM roles for service accounts:

```
helm install aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller -n kube-system  -f values.yml --dry-run
```

And it will work. But assuming that I have the following directory structure for my Kubernetes IaC:

```
  ▾ kubernetes/        
    ▸ apps/
    ▾ base/            
      ▾ alb_controller/
          README.md    
          values.yml   
      ▸ daemonsets/
```

I'll end up only with a `values.yml` and the `README.md` explaining what I did and which external chart I used.

What would be the best way to handle that type of dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to utilise another external chart as part of your chart, in which case, [Chart Dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/) will probably be what you're looking for.

Using Chart Dependencies you can tell Helm you want to install additional charts as part of your chart and Helm will automatically do that whenever you install or upgrade your chart.

Comment: Well, that is what is not clear to me. 

Let's say I just want a Load balancer, and I'm going to use the " AWS Load balancer controller" Should I create a chart that its only purpose is to have that dependency explicitly stated?

Is that the way to handle such single external dependencies cases? 

If I don't do that it feels that the only way to know what I've deployed is by checking documentation, that will get outdated, or maybe running a `helm list`. And the source of truth is not the source code any more.

Comment: If you are planning on just using a single chart without any additional features, then you don't need to create a new chart, just use `helm upgrade --install --values {path-to-your-values-file}` where the values file is any values you wish to override. If you have features that _build on_ the other charts, then you should use dependencies. For example, if I have a flask app chart that uses Redis, so I use the Redis chart as a dependency.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll just keep the values file in the code repository.